# Spring Email Sent Status

Tags: java, spring, email

Is there a way to check if the email was received or not using spring framework's email functions?

Comment: What do you want to do: check if an email that you have send is received by the receiver, or you you want to check your own mail account for new received mails?

Comment: Check if the email was received by the receipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check whether the email was received. The only errors that will be reported are those during the send process (Invalid address, wrong smtp credentials, etc.).

After the mail gets sent by the mail server, things are out of your business. What you could do is to check whether the receivers mail server sends a bounce (blocked email. full post box, no such address, etc.). But that have to happen outside the mail send process. Most likely done by a scheduler some time after emails have been sent.